# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

i am using laravel 5.1 its working on localhost but not working on server getting error

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

here is my code link

https://www.itextpad.com/XMkKhqCnof

help me

Comment: Please attach code to question (inline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `admin.blade.php` layout has this meta tag on its head:

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You must have (usually hidden) CSRF token field as part of your form, so just add

```
{{ csrf_field(); }}
```

somewhere in your form, and Laravel will do the rest.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Form builder remove this from your form. Laravel form builder automatically adds a hidden token field to your form when you do `Form::open()`

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSRF token in javascript what we mainly recommend is to put on meta and call from meta which this will come together with laravel 5.3 and above.

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

how to use it ?

if you are using 5.3 or above you can just use `token` to get the csrf_token that is not a magic you can see laravel have declare it in bootstrap.js with this code

`let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');`

if you are below ver. 5.3 can use the code above to get csrf token also

and also maybe the problem is not from the csrf token I suspect it is your javascript from data is not working try to use `new FormData()` instead hope thats help.

for more about form data can look at 
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)